# Present Perfect - the meaning

Tags: present-perfect, past-vs-present-perfect

What does the sentence for the native English speaker mean?

- The dog has stood there for a year.

Does it mean that it is still standing there? Or it means that it has been there for a year and now it is gone, dead or else?

Answer (score 2):

It definitely sounds like the dog is still standing there.

**The dog has stood there for a year** - it continues to stand there.

Although I would be more likely to say:

**The dog has been standing there for a year** - it continues to stand there.

If I wanted to say that the dog wasn't standing there any more, both sentences are the same but with **had**:

**The dog had stood there for a year** - it no longer stands there.

**The dog had been standing there for a year** - it no longer stands there.

Comment: As a side note, since no animal will stand in place for a year, the natural assumption is "the dog" is a statue (like the famous [Hachiko statue in Tokyo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hachik%C5%8D#/media/File:Hachiko_statue_shibuya.jpeg).  It's fine to stay a statue *stands* somewhere, that's just common English metaphor.